# Price Calculating formula in SQL

Tags: sql, formula

I have been using the following formula in excel but now I a trying with sql:
the formula:

```
Price field=(ROUND(Cost field/Constant number,1))-0.01
```

If the cost is 1.43 the price outcome would be according to this formula would be 2.59.
How can I write this formula is sql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple select and round

assuming your column are name `Cost field` and `Constant number`

```
    select ROUND(`Cost field`/`Constant number`,2)-0.01 as price
    from my_table
```

or using as `Constant number` = 30

```
  select ROUND(`Cost field`/30,2)-0.01 as price
    from my_table
```

and as suggestd  by Philipp be sure for the proper rounding  take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Comment: Do you know if the Ansi SQL standard mandates that the rounding rules must be "commercial rounding"? When the OP is working with money, that might be important.

Comment: @Philipp   .. correct answer udpated  with a brief suggestio for assuring the correct rounding . . in sql .. thanks  ..